# bind software to different network interfaces

Tags: networking

I have two different network interfaces, connected to 2 networks. One is an eth0 and the other one a wlan0. How can I tell a software to use only a specific interface?

Basically I want Firefox to use eth0 because it is the university lan network and I have to go to intranet sites, the other one is a wifi network open to the internet and I want to bind it to Chrome.

I'm working and I need to use intranet. So eth0 is my choice but eth0 is an intranet without internet access (obviously).
Since I want internet access I'm connected to wlan0 (university wifi for students).

The problem is if I have both connected sometimes the browser looks for www.stackoverflow.com using eth0. So I wanted to assign a browser to use only a specific interface.

Comment: Isn't routing a better solution for your problems?. I mean, that connections to ubuntu.stackexchange.com should use the same interface from any program.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You cannot bind client software to specific network interfaces, but
you can tell the kernel that you only want to use one network
interface for some IP addresses and the other one for everything else.
This is called "routing", and can be configured using the commands
`/sbin/route` and `/sbin/ip`.

If I read your question correctly, you want to connect to intranet IP
addresses using interface `eth0` and to the Internet using interface
`wlan0`.

If you run the command `ip route list`, you should see an output
like the following (numbers will be different, and also you can have
more lines in it):

```
$ ip route list
10.60.44.0/25 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.60.44.39  metric 1 
192.168.80.0/21 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.84.122  metric 2 
[...]
default via 10.60.44.1 dev eth0  proto static
```

The first two lines tell you about the networks connected to
interfaces `eth0` and `wlan0`: network traffic directed to computers
on those networks will be directly sent to them through the
corresponding interface.

The last line tells you what the "default route" is: if your computer
wants to talk to a computer on a network it is not attached to (e.g.,
the stackoverflow.com server), it will route traffic via `eth0`,
realying through host `10.60.44.1` (called the "default gateway").

So, to route Internet traffic thorugh `wlan0` you should ensure that
the last line in the `ip route list` output reads something like:

```
default via A.B.C.D dev wlan0 proto static
```

where `A.B.C.D` is the IP address of the gateway on the wireless LAN.
If the output does not contain "dev wlan0", you can change it with the
command:

```
sudo ip route change to default dev wlan0 via A.B.C.D
```

You can find out the correct `A.B.C.D` for `wlan0` in two ways:

1. Look into directory `/var/lib/dhcp3/`: you should find some
   `dhclient-...-wlan0.lease` files.  Open the most recent one and
   search for a line with the string `option router` in it: the rest
   of the line tells you the IP address `A.B.C.D`.
2. Ask your local network administrators.  (Probably the best thing to
   do, anyway.)

With this configuration, you should be able to:

- browse the Internet through `wlan0`
- browse your Intranet through `eth0`, *provided it is on a single network*.

If your intranet spans multiple networks, then you will need to add
routes for them - and this is definitely something that requires you
to interact with the local network admins. :-)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what if I want to bound dns (to include subdomains) rather than IP addresses?

Comment: @dierre In short: you can't, routing is based on IP addresses. The long story begins by telling that routing is a network layer 3 thing, so it won't even know about DNS names, whose resolution happens further up the networking protocol stack...

Comment: yeah yeah, I didn't mean with routing. I mean in general. Can it be done? Binding DNS to network interfaces?

Comment: @dierre What exactly do you want to do?  Making a DNS server answer only on a specific network interface?  Or having a DNS client (i.e., DNS resolution) use only a selected interface?

Comment: The second one. Because I was thinking of a different scenario. Let's say I have both interfaces connected to internet but I can use only one to download things (and throw away bandwith from it :P) from rapidshare or megaupload.

Comment: @dierre Sounds interesting. Maybe it's worth to make a new question out of it? :-)

Comment: @Riccardo Murri: http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/4988/2-network-interfaces-connected-to-internet-choose-the-one-to-use-according-to-th et voilà

Answer (score 3):

"ip netns" creates network namespaces.
You can then create virtual interfaces (ip link add... veth) and associate them to the namespaces.

The namespaces can be configured to use different routes for example (thus using different interfaces)

Then you can run commands in that namespace, that will use the created namespace..
"ip netns exec NAME cmd..."

Source:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man8/ip-netns.8.html