# Make different applications to use different connections

Tags: networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bind software to different network interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4872/bind-software-to-different-network-interfaces)

Is it possible to get an application like transmission to use the mobile broadband connection and say chrome to use the wifi connection?

Is there a way to set some rules for this?