# Use internet from 2 different sources at the same time

Tags: 12.04, networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bind software to different network interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4872/bind-software-to-different-network-interfaces)

I have an EVDO usb and wifi, I want to use them simultaneously. Say, for example, use EVDO for my torrent client and wifi for browsing. Both are connected and Ubuntu uses wifi by default, swithces to EVDO when I disconnect wifi.

P.S. I have tried using the Network interface option in Deluge but it doesn't help.

Comment: Someone had a similar problem here, and he got the solution: [link][1]


  [1]: http://superuser.com/questions/60605/multiple-network-connections-in-ubuntu-with-one-prefered-for-internet-traffic

Comment: @ThiagoPonte But that is not quite the same. What they are basically doing in that solution is making all the internal network route one connection (Which is a set of "static" IPs), and everything else through another. In this case, static routes are not an option, because you can never know the IP of all domains, and you cannot know which IP you will be connecting to in a torrent client.