# I am connected to 2 WLAN. How can i choose which program uses which connection?

Tags: wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bind software to different network interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4872/bind-software-to-different-network-interfaces)

I am connected to 2 WLANs.
One is using the integrated broadcom wireless adapter in my laptop
while the other is using an external USB TP-Link adapter.

How can i choose which program uses which connection ?

E.g I want firefox to use the integrated broadcom which is connected to SSID X while Chrome uses TP-Link USB adapter which is connected so SSID Y