# How can I use multiple network connections from the same host?

Tags: 14.04, networking, ifconfig

Suppose I could use both a wired and wireless connection; now, let's say I want to run firefox using the wireless and steam using the wired, how can I achieve that?
How can I plug them in? First connect wired then wireless? Then, what should I do next?
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64.

Cheers!

Comment: **Routing** is the only way I see to play with. But however, you cannot specify your web browser to use the defined network as it is just telling the underlying TCP-stack that it wants to connect to a specific IP-address. I presume its the same for steam... BTW, are the LAN & WLAN going to be the same network? and why would you want it to be so complicated just for two application?

Comment: No, they would go to two different networks (for example wired to my broadband and wirless to 4G). I want to do this because I want to be able to download from Steam/Firefox (4G) whilst playing a game on my broadband. All on the same host. I'm also potentially fine injecting and overriding calls to "bind" and "connect" if that would work.

Comment: Well, I've not tried it in experiment but I found something interesting, called "[**ip-netns**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/en/man8/ip-netns.8.html) which might give you a clue... have a read on it. and I hope some experts will answer to your question. :)

Comment: I would say there is no way to do like your question. Refer this answer for more information: http://askubuntu.com/a/4890/477744

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do you actually want that absolute mess which is needed to do this? No, you don't. Not if you need to ask. ;-)